# what is cordova ios config.xml file setting

Tags: cordova

cordova 9.0.0
ios 6.1.0
npm 6.14.4

`cordova create Sample com.sample.app Samples`

Config.xml add

`<platform name="ios">`
`<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true"/>`

`<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">`
`<param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine"/>`
`</feature>`

`<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine"/>`
`</platform>`

---- cordova platform add ios@6.1.0

LaunchStoryBoard add image with size 2732x2732
background color : white

when build app then app  is open but all button click not working.

what is missing, is my config.xml error??. Is it necessary to install Cocoapods on the mac side?

Comment: Did you set the click event for the button?. In this case, I don't see any requirement for installing Cocopods

Comment: browser and android are running. IOS reject. button not click

Comment: Button is in your HTML file or Storyboard? Could you post some code related to button here?

Comment: zz = zz + '<a href="/news/" class="tab-link">';
    zz = zz + '<i class="icon f7-icons ios-only" style="color:#f7f7f7;">keyboard</i>';
    zz = zz + '<i class="icon material-icons md-only"style="color:#f7f7f7;">keyboard</i>';
    zz = zz + '<span class="tabbar-label" style="color:#f7f7f7;">News</span>';
    zz = zz + '</a>';
    $$("#menu").html(zz); All menu created dynamic with app.js